# Jquery (nearby selector?)

Tags: jquery, selector

I'll explain with an example.

Our html is this:

```
<span>ok 
<span>1</span>
<a href=''></a>
</span>
```

and my jquery code is this:

```
$("a").live('click', function(){

var a = $(this).closest("span");

alert(a);

});
```

but it gives me "ok     1    " as a result.
i just want to have "1" only.

how can I choose "nearby tag"?

Comment: You can also use .prev('span') if it is guaranteed to be there.

Comment: use .siblings('span') or .prev('span')

Comment: siblings and filter. closest isn't meant for look at siblings or children, ancestors and current element only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var a = $(this).prev("span");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pF9AC/)**

FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()` since 1.7 I believe.

Comment: It would just return object, add .text() or .html() to it. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @OptimusPrime - no you're right, I was just giving the OP a jQuery selector that would target the correct element. He could then get what he needs from it using .text() or .html().

Answer (score 3):

Do not use .live, its deprecated.

```
$("a").click(function(){

var a = $(this).prev("span").text();

alert(a);

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/13/)**

Comment: @Sergio Thanks for appreciation.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for a sibling element, the previous one in this case. Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
   var a = $(this).prev("span");
   alert(a);
});
```

Note that `a` is a jQuery `object` and thus alerting it will just say `[object Object]`.

Also I changed `.live()` to `.on()` since `.live()` is deprecated. If your links are dynamically generated, the syntax is slightly different:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
   var a = $(this).prev("span");
   alert(a);
});
```

Comment: Both `first` and `last` are the same here in this case. `first()` is closest to the target element, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGAHD/).

Comment: Ah, that appears to be because `prev()` actually does only return a single item for each item that it is comparing against "Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements". Since `this` is a single element, `prev()` will only return a single element (or none if there is no match). `prevAll()` is maybe what you were thinking.